# Why is my callback in JavaScript not working for asynchronous results?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have been trying to set up callbacks to get the results from an asynchronous operation, but I have been unsuccessful so far. Have a look at the structure of the code below.

```
 var markers = []; //global array

 //The callback parameter is a reference to the function which is passed as an argument from the doAsyncOperation call
 function doAsyncOperation(callback) {
        var xmlArray = []; //the array that will hold the data that I'm trying to access later in the code
        downloadUrl("theXmlFile.xml", function (data) { //this is the async code that stores the results in an array called xmlArray    
            var xmlItems = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("row");
            xmlArray.push(theData); //this array is populated with data within this async code block

            //the logic works here; this part is not the issue
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            callback(xmlArray); //passing xmlArray as the result 
        }, Math.random() * 2000);
    }
 //the code below is the function call that should be getting the results from the doAsyncOperation function
 doAsyncOperation(function (xmlData) {
     alert(xmlData); //I am not able to see the data in xmlArray here
 });


 //the function below is called on Window.onload
 function initialize() {
     //In this function, I need to use the results in the xmlArray above.
     //I have tried saving the results into a global array, but it doesn't work because this function is called 
     //before the async operation completes.
 }
```

To sum it up, I am having trouble accessing the results of an asynchronous operation. As you can see, I have tried to set up callbacks to access the data, but I have to be doing something wrong. I have looked at similar questions here, but none of them seem to address the issue I'm having specifically. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables called `xmlArray`.

One is in the scope of doAsyncOperation.

The other is in the scope of the anonymous function you pass as an argument to `downloadUrl`.

Both of them start out by having empty arrays assigned to them.

The second one has some items pushed into it.

The first one is the one you pass to `callback`

Remove the line

```
var xmlArray = []; //this array is populated with data within this async code block
```

If you want the code in the anonymous function to modify the first array instead.

---

NB: Since you try to deal with the data `Math.random() * 2000` after **sending** the request, it is possible that you will not have received a response (triggering the anonymous function) before you try to pass it to `callback`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. However, that was a typo in the post. I didn't realize that I had already typed the first line that initialized `xmlArray`. Thank you for pointing that out, though. I have edited the question. My apologies.

Comment: @ic3man7019 — Then the section of my answer after the horizontal rule probably applies.

Comment: You are correct. I set the timeout to 5000 and, now, I'm at least getting the alert to show the data in the array. How would I access this data in the `initialize()` function? There are several operations that rely on this data inside the `initialize()` function.

Comment: Why are you using a timeout to trigger the callback instead of just using the anonymous function you pass to `downloadUrl`?

Comment: If you want to use the data in `initialize`, then call `initialize` and pass the data to it as an argument.

Comment: To be honest, that was the way I saw it done in an example that I was looking at for reference. Should I avoid doing it the way I have it here? (Setting the timeout, that is.)

Comment: @ic3man7019 — Using the timeout like that doesn't make any sense from the context provided. If you want to do something when some data is available, then it makes sense to do it when the data is available and not a random amount of time after you have sent the rest for that data.

Comment: I had the same thought. So, I should get rid of the `setTimeout` function, and put `callback(xmlArray)` inside the anonymous function that is passed to `downloadUrl`?

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this be like shown below - the `callback` is invoked after `downloadUrl` finishes

```
function doAsyncOperation(callback) {
    var xmlArray = []; 
    downloadUrl("theXmlFile.xml", function (data) { 
        var xmlItems = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("row");
        xmlArray.push(theData);
        callback(xmlArray); 
    });
 }
 doAsyncOperation(function (xmlData) {
     alert(xmlData); 
 });
```

Comment: This is correct. Quentin just beat you to it. Thank you, though. I appreciate the help.